# Open Source Variant Caller comparable to GATK Haplotype Caller?

Tags: mutations, software

Is there a Variant Caller comparable algorithmically and in performance to GATK Haplotype Caller but Open Source Compliant (non-restrictive use)?

Comment: You could also try asking on http://biostars.org.